# The set theoretical reason for $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is it that $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset $? I could not write a rigorous explanation for this.
Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Could you please tell us what is $f$ and what is $\phi$?

Comment: Are you writing the empty set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're trying to write $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ (i.e., the empty set and not the Greek letter $\phi$), then:

In general, $f(C)=\{f(a):a\in C\}$, in other words, the set of all outputs of $f$ on elements of $C$.

In the case of the emptyset, $f(\emptyset)=\{f(a):a\in\emptyset\}$.  Since $a\in\emptyset$ is *always* false, there are no $a$'s that satisfy the condition, so there are no $f(a)$'s in the set.  Hence, the set is empty.

Alternately, you can see this via contradiction, if $b\in f(\emptyset)$, then $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in\emptyset$, but since there are no $a$'s such that $a\in\emptyset$, there is no $a$ for which $b=f(a)$.